# how to parse json in app

Tags: ios, json

i have just started developing ios apps. 
I am writing an ios app, and need to parse 
json response got from server 
in iphone app

```
{
    "response": "login success",
    "response_code": 1
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Objective-C ?

Comment: show your code where are you getting problem, what have you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `NSJSONSerialization` to parse json response

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

                NSLog(@"json data is %@",jsonData);

                NSInteger success = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"response_code"] integerValue];
                NSString *response = [jsonData objectForKey:@"response"];

                NSLog(@"success is %d",success);
```

check the response code here

```
if(success == 1)
                {
                   // navigate to next or do whatever
                   // [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this framework: https://github.com/stig/json-framework
and `SBJsonParser` class to parse the JSon script. The below code will help you parse json response:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init] ;

NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *)[parser objectWithString:respString error:nil];
```

This code will convert your response string in the `respString` variable into an NSDictionary, and now you can extract each object by calling:

```
NSString* response = [dic objectForKey:@"response"];
```